# Search and Find a File do not work on all file types

Tags: search

I was testing my new SharePoint site, and found that several of my 'documents' in my library did not come up on search.
As I experimented with the problem, I have concluded that it does not find documents with file extensions like .sql or .sh  or even .txt even though these files are perfectly readable in notepad. Even searches on words in the title do NOT work.   How can I make the search tool find these documents outside of changing the file extension?  I DO NOT want these to be word documents as I need them to be 'clean' files.

Comment: TXT files should show up, not sure about .SQL. See this post for more information: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-NZ/library/jj219660.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint chooses files to index based on "Included File Types". Just add the missing file types in the `Search Service Application | File Types`.